# How to open a new activity by clicking on searchview bar?

Tags: android

I want to open a new search `activity` by clicking on the `searchview` bar in the `android` app. The `onclicklistener` is not working on the searchview bar.

```
 mySearchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.SearchView);
        //mySearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    mySearchView.setClickable(true);
    mySearchView.setIconified(false);


    mySearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new SearchView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


                    //perform your click operation here
                    Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, searchin.class);
                    startActivity(a);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**why you have to make searchview to do this ?**

create layout similar to searchview and make click event on it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`mySearchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, searchin.class);
startActivity(a);
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public void setOnSearchClickListener (View.OnClickListener listener)
```

Description from android developer website says.. Sets a listener to inform when the search button is pressed. This is only relevant when the text field is not visible by default. Calling setIconified(false) can also cause this listener to be informed.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setOnSearchClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)

Answer (score 0):

first get `ediTtext` of `SearchView` :

For `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) 
searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
```

For `android.widget.SearchView`:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.R.id.search_src_text);
```

then :

```
  editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, searchin.class);
            startActivity(a);
      }    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find **Editext** Of searchview.

**Edittext's** id in below code.

> val theTextArea =
>   findViewById(R.id.search_src_text)

Then set the clickListener on **Editext**  .

```
 theTextArea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          startActivity(Intent(MainActivity.this, searchin::java.class))
      }    
    });
```